# OAuth2-SpringBoot - Refresh token

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have configured my spring boot application to to provide oauth2 authorization.

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

       @Autowired
       private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

       @Autowired
       private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

       @Override
       public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.exceptionHandling()
               .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                        .and()
                        .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                        .and()
                        .csrf()
                        .disable()
                        .headers()
                        .frameOptions().disable()
                        .exceptionHandling().and()
                        .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/v1/login/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/v1/test/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
            }
        }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

        private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";
        private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "clientid";
        private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
        private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "tokenValidityInSeconds";
        private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                     .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                   .withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                   .scopes("read", "write")
                   .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_USER.name())
                   .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
                   .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                   .accessTokenValiditySeconds(
                    propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 1800))
                   .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(100000);
            }

        @Override
        public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
            this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, ENV_OAUTH);
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public CustomPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CustomPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").antMatchers("/api/login/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http.httpBasic().realmName("WebServices").and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")
            .authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }
    }
}

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Inject
    private AccountDao accountDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        Account userFromDatabase = null;
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase();
        if (lowercaseLogin.contains("@")) {
            userFromDatabase = accountDao.getByEmailId(lowercaseLogin);
        } else {
            userFromDatabase = accountDao.getByPhoneNumber(lowercaseLogin);
        }

        if (userFromDatabase != null) {
            if (!userFromDatabase.getActivated()) {
                throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
            }
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = userFromDatabase.getRoles().stream()
                    .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getRoleName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userFromDatabase.getAccountName(),
                    userFromDatabase.getAccountPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the " + "database");
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try to get the refresh token after the access token expires, I always get

> 2017-07-10 00:57:40.797  INFO 68115 --- [nio-9090-exec-4]
>   o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error:
>   NoSuchClientException, No client with requested id: 12345678

Though there is a row in the db with the column phone number 12345678 and account name as 12345678.

https://myTestWebServices/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=f4cc8213-3f2b-4a30-965b-6feca898479e

I have the header set to `Authorization: Basic xxx` 
`xxx` is the same that I use to get the `access_token` so I am assuming it works fine.

But the output is always this

> { "error": "unauthorized", "error_description": "User 12345678 was
>   not found in the database" }

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. And explain your OAuth2 flow how you're getting the refresh token.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar please check now

Comment: have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: did you get any solutions?

Comment: i have the same issue, with grant type password i am able to get tokens , but with grant type "refresh token" getting exception user not found because user details service (loaduserByUsername method) getting username as null, but with grant type password its coming properly

Comment: @AmitPatel, are you sending the request as POST or GET?

Answer (score 7):

You should be passing **clientId** and **client secret** (these are different from **userId** and **password**) while fetching `access token` using `refresh token`. Not sure what are passing in `authorisation` headers.

You seem to be having two different issues. When do you get the below error:

> { "error": "unauthorized", "error_description": "User 12345678 was not
>   found in the database" }

Can you verify if the user is successfully **authenticated** and if the service returned access token and refresh token? You may place debug pointer in `UserDetailsService` and check the flow.

Try to validate the configuration by following below steps:

Get Refresh Token, assuming you are using

```
curl -vu clientId:clientSecret 'http://your_domain_url/api/oauth/token?username=userName&password=password&grant_type=password'
```

*here **username** and **password** are different from **client ID** and **client secret***
This should return you refresh token and access token in the response

```
{"access_token":"d5deb98a-75fc-4f3a-bbfd-e5c87ca2ca6f","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"b2be4291-57e9-4b28-b114-feb3406e030d","expires_in":2,"scope":"read write"}
```

The above response has got access token and refresh token. Whenever the access token expires, you can use refresh token to fetch access token like below:

```
curl -vu clientId:clientSecret 'http://your_domain_url/api/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=refresh_token_value'
```

Response:

```
{"access_token":"13fd30f9-f0c5-414e-9fbd-a5e2f9f3e4a7","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"b2be4291-57e9-4b28-b114-feb3406e030d","expires_in":2,"scope":"read write"}
```

Now you can use the access token make your service calls

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer 13fd30f9-f0c5-414e-9fbd-a5e2f9f3e4a7" http://your_domain_url/api/mySecureApi
```

Answer (score 2):

I think for the password `grant_type`, a clientId and clientSecret are required. You pass the Base64 encoded clientId and clientSecret instead of the Access Token in the `Authorization` header. Like so:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [base64encode(clientId:clientSecret)]" "https://yourdomain.com/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[yourRefreshToken]"
```

I'm assuming you first get the token like this (which you didn't say even though I asked):

```
curl --data "grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass&client_id=my_client" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token"
```

Also, put a breakpoint in `loadUserByUsername` and check if it's invoked for the failed refresh attempt.

Comment: i also have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Just add UserDetailsService then it will work

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }
```

and request

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=myclient&client_secret=secret&refresh_token=<token>
```